# laravel 4 authentication and login not working for me

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-4

I'm tearing my hair out over this login problem. Hopefully someone will be able to see this right off the bat and I've just been staring at it too long.
Simply put, I can create a user but can't get the same user logged into the system.

Here is the code that successfully stores the new user…

```
public function store()
{
    //initialise new user
    $user = new User();

    //fill user object
    $user->firstname = Input::get('firstname');
    $user->lastname = Input::get('lastname');
    $user->username = Input::get('username');
    $user->email = Input::get('email');
    //$user->password = Hash::make('password');
            $user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
    $user->role_id = '2';
    //submit user object
    $success = $user->save();
    if ($success) {
        $user->save();
        return Redirect::route('users.index');
    }

    $errors = $user->errors()->all();
    return Redirect::route('users.create')
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($errors)
        ->with('message', 'You have errors on your form.');
}
```

Here is my login form to log in as the above user...

```
{ Form::open(array('url' => 'login')) }}
<ul>

    <li>
        {{ Form::label('username', 'Username:') }}
        {{ Form::text('username') }}
    </li>

    <li>
        {{ Form::label('password', 'Password:') }}
        {{ Form::password('password') }}
    </li>

    <li>
        {{ Form::submit('Submit', array('class' => 'btn btn-info')) }}
    </li>
</ul>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Here is the route:

```
Route::post('login', function() {
$userdata = array(
    'username' => Input::get('username'),
    'password' => Input::get('password')
);

//echo Hash::make('password');
if (Auth::attempt($userdata)) {
    echo "success";

}
else {
    //print_r($userdata);
    echo "fail";
}
});
```

Unfortunately… when I create a user and attempt to login everything always echoes fail.

Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.
DS

***** ok… corrected above.

Comment: I know nothing about this framework, but my hunch is that your Store method should be `$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));` Otherwise you're just literally hashing the string 'password'...

Comment: this was it! argh! thanks so much - this was the fresh eyes job I needed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have

```
$user->password = Hash::make('password');
```

it should be:

```
$user->password = Hash::make(Input::get('password'));
```

Your user creation code is giving everyone the password 'password'.

Comment: yep - Kormey alluded to that in his comment. thanks.